# Initialize initializer_list from template parameters

Tags: c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I need to set up a large number of std::vector in a lookup library. The all have the structure:

```
{N, N, ..., -N, -N}
```

I can do that with a number of templated functions:

```
template<int N>
static constexpr std::initializer_list<int> H2 = {N, -N};
template<int N>
static constexpr std::initializer_list<int> H4 = {N, N, -N -N};
...
```

from which I can simply do:

```
std::vector<int> v22 = H2<3>    
std::vector<int> v35 = H3<5>
etc.
```

But would there be a way to include also the numbers 2, 4 etc. as a template parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using `std::integer_sequence` and variable template specialization:

```
template <typename, int N>
static constexpr std::initializer_list<int> HImpl;

template <int N, int... Is>
static constexpr std::initializer_list<int> HImpl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, N>
    = {(Is < sizeof...(Is) / 2) ? N : -N...};

template <int Count, int N>
static constexpr auto H = HImpl<std::make_index_sequence<Count>, N>;
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = H<10, 1>;
    for(int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
> ```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q3jYa6NNaE8YQnkH)

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!